# Reemplazar valores en un array con javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Que tal? tengo el siguiente grafico

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito agregar una funcion o arreglo que recorra el array data y reemplaze los valores cero por null,
O alguna forma de hacer dinamico el grafico, ya que me grafico los valores cero.

Lo ideal seria que solo me grafique los valores que tiene, para que el tamaño del grafico cambie.
Espero alguno me pueda ayudar.

Adjunto codigo js

```
function setPageValues () {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(drawVisualization).getValuesFromSS("J11:Q24");
       }
```

`google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

  function drawVisualization(values) {
    // Some raw data (not necessarily accurate)
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Dia', 'HR Pre y Post Producción', 'WCM (WO+Otros)', 'Laboratorio', 'BOX', 'Revisión','Hrs Extra por Producción', 'Calidad', 'Fuera de Línea', 'AM'],
      [values[0][1], values[1][1], values[2][1], values[3][1], values[4][1], values[5][1], values[6][1], values[7][1], values[8][1], values[9][1]],
      [values[0][2], values[1][2], values[2][2], values[3][2], values[4][2], values[5][2], values[6][2], values[7][2], values[8][2], values[9][2]],
      [values[0][3], values[1][3], values[2][3], values[3][3], values[4][3], values[5][3], values[6][3], values[7][3], values[8][3], values[9][3]],
      [values[0][4], values[1][4], values[2][4], values[3][4], values[4][4], values[5][4], values[6][4], values[7][4], values[8][4], values[9][4]],
      [values[0][5], values[1][5], values[2][5], values[3][5], values[4][5], values[5][5], values[6][5], values[7][5], values[8][5], values[9][5]],
      [values[0][6], values[1][6], values[2][6], values[3][6], values[4][6], values[5][6], values[6][6], values[7][6], values[8][6], values[9][6]],
      [values[0][7], values[1][7], values[2][7], values[3][7], values[4][7], values[5][7], values[6][7], values[7][7], values[8][7], values[9][7]]
    ]);

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([0, 1,{calc: "stringify", sourceColumn: 1, type: "string", role: "annotation"},2,{calc: "stringify", sourceColumn: 2, type: "string", role: "annotation"},3,{calc: "stringify", sourceColumn: 3, type: "string", role: "annotation"},4,{calc: "stringify", sourceColumn: 4, type: "string", role: "annotation"},5,{calc: "stringify", sourceColumn: 5, type: "string", role: "annotation"},
    6,{calc: "stringify", sourceColumn: 6, type: "string", role: "annotation"},7,{calc: "stringify", sourceColumn: 7, type: "string", role: "annotation"},8,{calc: "stringify", sourceColumn: 8, type: "string", role: "annotation"},9,{calc: "stringify", sourceColumn: 9, type: "string", role: "annotation"},
    ]);

    var options = {
      seriesType: 'bars',
      title: "HORAS EXTRAS",
      fontSize:15,              
      fontName:'Nunito Sans',
      backgroundColor: {stroke: '#B6DEFA', strokeWidth:0, fill:'#172d5b',rx: 6, ry: 6},
      chartArea: {'width': '95%', 'height': '70%'},
      bar: {groupWidth: "70%"},
      legend: { position: 'bottom',textStyle: {color: '#FFFFFF', fontSize: 11}},
      annotations: {textStyle: {fontName:'Nunito Sans', fontSize:11, color: '#FFFFFF'}, alwaysOutside: true},
      titleTextStyle: {color: '#FFFFFF',fontSize:20},
      hAxis: {textStyle: {color: '#B6DEFA'}, titleTextStyle: {color: '#B6DEFA'}},
      vAxis: {textStyle: {color: '#172d5b'}, titleTextStyle: {color: '#B6DEFA'}, gridlines: {count : 0}, viewWindow:{max:10}},
      animation:{duration: 1000, easing: 'out',startup: true}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(view, options);
  }`

Saludos

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Puedes usar la función [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map)

Recorre el array y te devuelve uno nuevo con el resultado de la llamada a la función indicada.

Por ejemplo:

```
numberos = [ -3, 2, -1, 5 ];
valorAbsoluto = numberos.map(function(elemento) {
    return Math.abs(elemento);
});

console.log(valorAbsoluto); // Muestra [ 3, 2, 1, 5 ]
```

En tu caso, como tienes un array bidimensional, necesitarás dos `map`. Sería algo como:

```
values = values.map(function(arrayInterior) {
    return arrayInterior.map(function(elemento) {
        return elemento === 0 ? null : elemento;
    });
});
```

Ahora todos los valores `0` serán `null`.

Para tu otra pregunta. Cómo quitar el array que tiene todo ceros. Échale un ojo a las funciones [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) y [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/every).

Sobre `filter()`, la documentación dice:

> El método filter() crea un nuevo array con todos los elementos que cumplan la condición implementada por la función dada.

Sobre `every()`, la documentación dice:

> El método every() devuelve un booleano, true si todos los elementos en el arreglo pasan la condición implementada por la función dada y false si alguno no la cumple.

Puedes usar esas funciones así:

```
values = [[1, -3, 0, 1, 2, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, -3, 1]]

values = values.filter(function (arrayInterno) {
  return !arrayInterno.every(function (elemento) {
    return elemento === 0 || typeof elemento === 'string'
  });
});

console.log(values); // Muestra [[ 1, -3, 0, 1, 2, 0], [0, -3, 1]]
```

Lo que hace el código de arriba es coger el array `values`, cada subarray pasa a la función `filter()` como `arrayInterno`. Dentro de la función `filter()` le decimos que devuelva `false` si todos los elementos son 0, de esta comprobación se encarga la función `every()`. Al devolver `false` el `filter()` ese subarray no se devuelve.

Luego puedes tener las otras funciones que indiqué arriba, para sobreescribir de nuevo la variable `values` y cambiar los 0 por `null`. O puedes ingeniártelas para ponerlo todo en la misma función.

Al final sería un código así:

```js
var valoresOriginales = [['Lun', 1, -4, 0, 1, 2, 0], ['Mar', 0, 0, 0], ['Mie', 0, -3, 1]]

var valoresFiltrados = valoresOriginales.filter(function (arrayInterno) {
  return !arrayInterno.every(function (elemento) {
    return elemento === 0 || typeof elemento === 'string'
  });
});


var valoresSinCeros = valoresFiltrados.map(function(arrayInterior) {
    return arrayInterior.map(function(elemento) {
        return elemento === 0 ? null : elemento;
    });
});

console.log('Originales: ', valoresOriginales);
console.log('Filtrados: ', valoresFiltrados);
console.log('Sin ceros: ', valoresSinCeros);
```

Comment: Como quedaria en mi proyecto? porque probe agregarlo depues y no funciona

Comment: listo, lo pude hacer funcionar como me dijiste, como puedp hacer para eliminar el array que tiene todos ceros? osea me queda por ejemplo  [[1,1,1,1][0,0,0,0]] EL el que tiene todos ceros como lo puedo borrar? para que me quede solo el que tiene [[1,1,1,1]]???

Comment: @MTProducciones deberías echarle un ojo a la página de la documentación de los [`array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array) y ver qué opciones tienes disponibles. He editado mi respuesta para poner también lo que quieres de filtrar los que son todo ceros.

Comment: pero solo me funciona para cuando el largo de la matriz es var valoresOriginales = [['LUN',1, 2], ['MAR', 0, 0], ['MIE', -3, 1]] y yo tengo var valoresOriginales = [['LUN',1, 2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], ['MAR'',0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], ['MIE',1, 2,4,5,6,0,0,0,0]]

Comment: Pues podemos poner que si todos son texto o `0` elimine ese subarray. En lugar de `return elemento === 0;` dentro del `every()` sería `return elemento === 0 || typeof elemento === 'string'` Lo edito en el código.

Comment: Solo comentar que esas funciones no te funcionarán en algunos navegadores antiguos (es5)

Comment: Pero a estas alturas la pregunta original ya está respondida. Y por otro lado, ya tienes las herramientas que necesitas. Antes de seguir preguntando, intenta pensar qué es lo que está haciendo el código y cómo podrías cambiarlo para o que necesitas. No necesitas que yo te lo diga, solo busca un poco como funcionan las cosas y explora/experimenta, así es como vas a aprender mejor, no leyendo y obteniendo las respuestas.

Comment: @SebastianPaduano según [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_versions.asp) ECMAScript 5 es compatible con todos los exploradores modernos. Chrome 23+, Firefox 21+, IE 9+, Edge 10+, Safari 6+ y Opera 15+. No sé los demás, pero me parece que está bastante extendido ya.

Comment: Listo ya converti el grafico en dinamico, muchas gracias! @ArianJM

Comment: @ArianJM em sí, pero tu funcion .map no funcionará en es5.

Comment: @SebastianPaduano Pues la [documentación de Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Browser_compatibility) dice que si funciona en todos los navegadores